# Hamiltonian - Fourier transform of order parameter

Tags: homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics, field-theory, fourier-transform, hamiltonian

I have a rather simple task, but it seems I can't move forward with the solution. I have a Hamiltonian as seen in the picture. I have to use the Fourier transform of the order parameter $\phi(x)$ and rearrange so as to get $H(\tilde{\phi})$. Here is what I managed to do so far:

[image]

Any idea how to simplify the squared integrals?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I'll give it a try. I guess you have to be careful that after transforming you get two different quantized momenta. You're then summing/integrating over $q',q$. Leaving out the normalization constants:
\begin{align}
H[\tilde{\phi}] &= \int dx \left[k_1 \left(  \partial_x \int dq  \tilde{\phi}(q)e^{-iqx}\right)\left(\partial_x \int dq' \tilde{\phi}(q') e^{-iq'x}\right)+k_2 \int dq dq' \tilde{\phi}(q)\tilde{\phi}(q')  e^{-i(q+q')x} \right]\\
&=\int dx \left[-k_1 \int dq dq' qq'\tilde{\phi}(q)\tilde{\phi}(q')  e^{-i(q+q')x} + k_2 \int dq dq' \tilde{\phi}(q)\tilde{\phi}(q') e^{-i(q+q')x} \right]\\
&=-k_1 \int dq dq' qq'\tilde{\phi}(q)\tilde{\phi}(q')  \delta(q+q')+ k_2 \int dq dq' \tilde{\phi}(q)\tilde{\phi}(q') \delta(q+q')\\
&= \int dq \left[ k_1 q^2 \tilde{\phi}(q)\tilde{\phi}(-q) + k_2  \tilde{\phi}(q)\tilde{\phi}(-q)\right]
\end{align}